# Unit testing entity framework

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

When unit testing with NHibernate I will typically have tests that create and save an object, clear the session (session.Clear()) then retrieve the object from the database.

What's the equivalent of Session.Clear() with EF4?

Example test:

```
    [Test]
    public void Can_create_and_save_a_default_account()
    {
        var account = new Account();

        _db.Accounts.AddObject(account);
        _db.SaveChanges();

        int id = account.AccountId;

        // clear session

        var fromDb = _db.Accounts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.AccountId == id);
        Assert.IsNotNull(fromDb);
    }
```

Comment: For a good article on unit testing entity framework see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff714955.aspx

Answer (score 3):

That will be recreating your `DataContext`-derived class (`_db` in your case).

Answer (score 0):

You could mock your remote database with in-memory database. [Here is example](http://druss.pp.ua/2013/03/unit-test-data-access-layer-entity-framework-with-in-memory-database/)
SO after each test you will start from scratch.